# Need to upload/copy ALL files from specific local directory to AWS S3 bucket using AWS CLI on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, ubuntu-22.04

I am working on an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop using AWS CLI.  I am trying to upload ALL files located in a specific local directory to our S3 bucket using AWS CLI but I'm getting an error.  Here is my command and the error:

```
ms@ms01:~$ aws s3 cp /home/ms/Downloads/TWU/mp3/ s3://abc.org/v2/ –-recursive
```

The error I'm getting is:  **Unknown options:  --recursive**

Any help/direction would be appreciated.   Thanks.

Comment: try `aws s3 sync`

Answer (score 3):

Try putting `--recursive` earlier in the command:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive /home/ms/Downloads/TWU/mp3/ s3://abc.org/v2/
```

Alternatively, the `sync` command always includes all sub-directories and only copies files that are not already in the destination (so it can be run multiple times to only copy new/changed files):

```
aws s3 sync /home/ms/Downloads/TWU/mp3/ s3://abc.org/v2/
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an old version of `awscli`. Try Updating it through: 
 `pip install awscli -U`